# Creating an equation for car prices depreciation

Tags: regression

I am trying to develop an app to help users find the best money for the value of cars based on the real price of car ownership, which is a sum of depreciation, gas consumption, maintenance, and insurance.

I need to convert depreciation prices into an equation. The depreciation equation is not linear and may have several gradients, as shown in the following graph. In most depreciation graphs, the curve initially drops fast and becomes more subtle later.

See the following graph:
[image]

How such an equation can be made?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Tal.  Are you asking how to write down or code equations for the (apparently) piecewise linear graphs you have plotted, or are you asking for something else?  Could you clarify what a "statistic" equation is and how that differs from the usual meaning of "equation" or "formula"?

Comment: Thanks, Whuber. I reframed my question in the hope that the question would be clearer.

Comment: That's appreciated, but your aim is still vague: what *kind* of formula are you looking for?  Must it exactly reproduce the graph?  Or at least produce a graph that passes through the vertices of your graph? Or just approximate it somehow?